# How best can you display a value which is based on the pattern of other values (not the values themselves)

Tags: user-expectation, machine-learning

I have an unusual situation due to some underlying fuzzy logic and machine learning algorithms where I have a `priority` value of an item, say, low, medium and high.

The `priority` assessment is based on ~20 underlying calculations and the users are seeking to better understand how the result is arrived at.

Whilst I can (albeit with its own considerations) display the underlying calculation values even from these the user can't easily tell why something has a high, med, low priority as the combination of the underlying calculations isn't easy to rationalise, it's not directly weighted and it's not a simple overall score, average or anything.

The priority is based on how common the pattern of results is, which in turn is based on the data itself rather than anything absolute.

The whole situation isn't aided by the fact the users are more familiar with simpler tools where there are rules which are met or broken and it's easy to understand why a rule has been broken.

A suitable analogy might be how police identify suspicious cars to stop, there are some obvious things like speeding or weaving all over the road, but equally, someone driving **too** normally might be an indicator they are trying to hide something and the normality could be considered abnormal.

So my longwinded question is whether there is any research into displaying values where the result is related to the underlying data but not directly? or whether there are any generic approaches for aiding understandability when the methodology is necessarily complex.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure there is an answer for this, because in the process of creating this logic/interface, some solid design principles are being contradicted and you will have to untangle them to make your life easier later down the track (imagine if you had to make changes and updates to this).

If I understand the question correctly, you are trying to display values which uses a combination of factors to derive at a priority value. A common example of this is the Google Search Rank algorithm, which uses some well-known and published (plus some unknown - we believe anyway) factors to score the search results. So the value doesn't have to be shown explicitly but the users understand that there is a bit of fuzziness in the results returned (and expect it to improve or get better depending on how much we share with Google).

I think there are a number of plausible explanations for why the maths is not shown to the user:

- it can create more confusion due to its complexity
- it can end up modifying the behaviour of the user
- it might not be well-understood enough or make sense to display (e.g. machine learning algorithm models like neural networks that even the developers don't fully understand)
- it might not really add much value to the information being provided (i.e. nothing the users can do with that information)

So there are some common strategies that can be used, each with their own trade-off. You can choose to:

1. Display values as is and all the factors in its full glory and see if people will eventually learn and understand it (with some explanations).
2. Display a simplified version that provides the gist of how it works, and then provide a long-winded explanation for those that are interested in a link or somewhere else from the main interface.
3. Don't display anything other than the priority value but provide some brief explanation of how it works.
4. Don't display the priority value and let it be a 'trade secret' of some sort.

Each of these strategies (or combinations therefore) will create a different experience for various types of users, so you'll have to do some research and testing to figure out what works the best for the objective you are trying to achieve.